# How to avoid using lot of I's in the personal essay?

Tags: american-english, writing, letter-writing, writing-advice

I am writing my statement of purpose for applying to grad school.
When I read my statement of purpose I see a lot of "I"s:

> I did this
>   I worked on this
>   I want to
>   I got to learn this
>   I got to work on that
>   I got to learn that
>   I did that

I just realized I am so bad in writing. How do I avoid using lots of "I"s?

Comment: This is a dulicate of http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/7074/4626 which got moved to Writers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because EL&U doesn't do style reviews or provide writing advice.  This question *might* be better placed on [Writers.SE], but I can't speak for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole point of the personal statement is to give the admissions officer a convincing impression of what kind of person you are, your passions and strengths, your most valued experiences, etc. It is pretty much impossible to do this without liberal use of the first person pronouns.

In fact, if you try and avoid using *I* you may well end up with some bland passive constructions or formulaic expressions that will not help you stand out from the thousands of other applicants.

Of course, this does not mean that you should start each sentence with *I*. There are many other ways to ensure sentence variety. For example:

> After finishing my three months as an intern, I ..
>
> One of my most memorable experiences was when I ..
>
> Six months later I ..

Here is an extract from [advice from Indiana University](https://wts.indiana.edu/writing-guides/personal-statements-and-application-letters.html),

> Consider The “I” Problem: This is a personal statement; using the
>   first person pronoun “I” is acceptable. Writers often feel rather
>   self-conscious about using first person excessively, either because
>   they are modest or because they have learned to avoid first and second
>   person (“you”) in any type of formal writing. Yet in this type of
>   writing using first person is essential because it makes your prose
>   more lively. Using third person can result in a vague and overly wordy
>   essay. While starting every sentence with “I” is not advisable,
>   remember that you and your experiences are the subject of the essay.

You will find many pages of similar advice if you Google on "*writing an application*" and "*first person*".

Comment: A more general version of the I problem is that writers scanning over their work can see repetition of some words that don't actually stand out as heavy repetition when reading normally rather than scanning anxiously (*I* but also tags like *said*, copulas, etc.). It's just not the problem people convince themselves it is.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is to turn your sentences around so that *I* isn't the subject.

> I got to learn a lot about neuroscience.
>
> Neuroscience was a fascinating subject because...

-

> I worked on designs and blueprints for building a rocket ship.
>
> A favorite project was designing blueprints for building a rocket ship.

Etc.

Comment: Sometimes you can still use pronouns that draw attention to your own involvement without the direct use of 'I', if only to mix in a bit of variety to the familiar 'I'-centered format. For instance, "One of my favorite projects was drawing up the blueprints for a rocket ship".

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, please don't let anyone talk you into over-using the impersonal "one". When my Norwegian colleagues fell into that trap, I would ask them whether they were Queen Elizabeth II, explaining that, for the rest of us, it should not be used for autobiography, only for what it says on the tin, namely impersonals. For instance, I might say, "In Africa, one has to bribe traffic policemen", but if I say, "One is now living in Douala", I sound like the Queen -- or a pompous twit.

I like Shoe's answer and am upvoting.